# How do I map a Mollweide projection onto a sphere?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, geodesy, projection

I have this Mollweide projection of the Earth circa 600 million years ago ([http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~rcb7/370moll.jpg](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/%7Ercb7/370moll.jpg)).(1)

[image: Mollweide projection of the earth]

I want to map this onto a sphere.  My results have big black splotches in the Pacific Ocean and the continents are distorted, because the code I used also mapped the black corners of the image to the sphere.  I need to map just the central ellipse.  What sort of code should I use?  Perhaps I need to first convert the image to an equirectangular projection.

(1) Image credit: [Ron Blakey, NAU Geology](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/%7Ercb7/)

Answer (score 20):

I know it's been more than two years since the question was asked but please allow me to answer nevertheless for future reference.

According to Wikipedia articles on [Mollweide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection) and [equirectangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) projections, the function `mollweidetoequirect` that converts the former to the latter can be constructed as follows:

```
lat[y_, rad_:1] := ArcSin[(2 theta[y, rad] + Sin[2 theta[y, rad]])/Pi];
lon[x_, y_, rad_:1, lonzero_: 0] := lonzero + Pi x/(2 rad Sqrt[2] Cos[theta[y, rad]]);
theta[y_, rad_:1] := ArcSin[y/(rad Sqrt[2])];
mollweidetoequirect[{x_, y_}] := {lon[x, y], lat[y]};
```

where `lonzero` and `radius` are chosen to be zero and one, respectively, for the transformation function. This means that the left-hand border of a transformed image will correspond to the meridian, and that we're going to use the texture on a unit sphere. For a sphere of radius $R$, the abscissae of a Mollweide image are in $[-2 R \sqrt{2}, 2 R \sqrt{2}]$ and the ordinates in $[-R \sqrt{2}, R \sqrt{2}]$.

To transform a map image, we need `ImageForwardTransformation` (**not** `ImageTransformation`) and tell Mathematica the ranges of coordinates of the image in both directions.

```
mollweide = Import["http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~rcb7/370moll.jpg"]
equirect = ImageForwardTransformation[
  mollweide,
  mollweidetoequirect,
  DataRange -> {{-2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}},
  PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: equirectangular image]

To map the texture onto a sphere, we need a plotting function that allows us to use `TextureCoordinateFunction`. There are quite a few to choose from, but because our equirectangular coordinates are in the form of `{longitude, latitude}`, the most convenient plotting function would be the one that allows us to use the spherical coordinates for `TextureCoordinateFunction`. According to its documentation, the only option is `SphericalPlot3D`:

```
globe[texture_] := SphericalPlot3D[
  1,
  {theta, 0, Pi},
  {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[texture]],
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, -#4} &),
  Mesh -> None,
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  Axes -> False,
  Boxed -> False
];
globe[equirect]
```

[image: equirectangular image mapped to a globe]

According to the documentation of `TextureCoordinateFunction`, `#4` stands for θ and `#5` for φ. But it's not clear what convention Mathematica uses for the spherical coordinates. The documentation of `SphericalPlot3D` suggests that θ is the polar angle (which corresponds to latitude) and φ the azimuthal angle (which corresponds to longitude), hence `{#5, -#4}`. The minus sign is needed because the vertical axis of image data [is in the reverse direction of the usual y-axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32377/5906).

Here's another example using an image of the cosmic microwave background taken by PLANCK, which is often shown in the Mollweide projection.

[image: PLANCK CMB]

```
mollweide = Import["http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2013/03/planck_cmb/12583930-4-eng-GB/Planck_CMB.jpg"]
equirect = ImageForwardTransformation[
  mollweide,
  mollweidetoequirect,
  DataRange -> {{-2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}}
];
globe[equirect]
```

[image: PLANCK CMB]

The option `PlotRange -> All` is omitted to remove some more white space.

Comment: Thanks! But what's the semicolon at rad_:1 for? I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: @СимонТыран You're welcome. For the colon: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html

Answer (score 9):

It might be better to start from the rectangular global maps that are available [here](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~rcb7/rect_globe.html) and then use part of the method proposed by PlatoManiac.

This is the earth in early Devonian time:

[image: earth map in early Devonian time]

```
map = Import["http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~rcb7/400marect.jpg"];
pic = SphericalPlot3D[1, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
    TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[map]], 
    Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
    Boxed -> False]
```

There should be a way to transform your original image into an image that corresponds to an equirectangular projection by using `ImageTransformation[]`.