# Efficiently generating 2-D Gaussian random fields on the sphere

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, random

### Context

A couple of years ago I posted this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4829/1089) for an efficient code to generate an n-D Gaussian random field (sometimes called processes in other fields of research), which has applications in cosmology.

For instance, the function `GaussianRandomField`  would work as follows in 2D

```
 u = GaussianRandomField[] //Chop// GaussianFilter[#, 1] &;
 Image[u] // ImageAdjust
```

[image: a 2D GRF]

### Question

> I am interested in an efficient way to proceed on the sphere.

### Motivation

I would eventually like to make maps like this  map of the [`Cosmic Microwave Background`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) seen by the [`Planck satellite`](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Planck).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

using [`this code`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13411/1089).

*Possible difficulties*

It most likely involves fast Spherical Harmonic transforms of relatively high order? One possibility might be to link to the [`Healpix library`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEALPix.html), but hopefully it would be an overkill.

### Feeble attempt

Extracting the transformation code from the above mentioned page

```
invmollweide[{x_, y_}] := 
 With[{theta = ArcSin[y]}, {Pi x/(2 Cos[theta]), 
   ArcSin[(2 theta + Sin[2 theta])/Pi]}]
```

I can generate a  map:

```
     Clear[alms]; lmax = 48;
Do[alms[l,  m] = (Random[NormalDistribution[]] + I Random[NormalDistribution[]])
  /Sqrt[(l + 2) (l + 1)]; 
  alms[l, -m] = (-1)^m  Conjugate@alms[l, m];, {l, 0, lmax}, {m, 0, l}];

Do[alms[l, 0] = (Random[NormalDistribution[]])/Sqrt[(l + 2) (l + 1)]; , {l, 0, lmax}];

Clear[field];
field[θ_, ϕ_] = Sum[alms[l, m] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ], {l, 0, lmax}, {m, -l, l}];

fieldN = Compile[{θ, ϕ}, field[θ, ϕ] // Evaluate];

dat = ParallelTable[fieldN[θ, ϕ], {θ, 0, Pi, Pi/128.}, {ϕ, 0.,2 Pi, 2 Pi/256.}] // N;
```

and then plot it:

```
im = Re[dat] // Image // ImageAdjust// Colorize[#,
 ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap"] &;
 mol=ImageTransformation[im, invmollweide, 
 DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi/2, Pi/2}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}},Padding-> White]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**But**

1. The production of the map is rather slow…
2. The code breaks down e.g. at `lmax=64`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

probably because of the accuracy of the spherical harmonics
(whereas in astronomy people routinely use `lmax = 4096` or more).

It's a pity because Mathematica allows for some cool [`visualization`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27496/1089).

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> True, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, 1 - #4} &), 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Texture[im], Specularity[White, 50]], 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

See also [`this`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79868/1089)

### Possible Extension: random vector field on sphere

One can also define vector fields on the sphere as follows

```
fc[phi_] := 
  Block[{theta}, 
   If[Abs[phi] == Pi/2, phi, theta /. 
     FindRoot[2 theta + Sin[2 theta] == Pi Sin[phi], {theta, phi}]]];
cart[{lambda_, phi_}] := 
 With[{theta = fc[phi]}, {2/Pi*lambda Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}]
```

Then, if we define [`VectorSphericalHarmonicV`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25078/1089)

```
Clear[ϵ];(*Polarization vector*)
ϵ[λ_] = Switch[λ, -1, {1, -I, 0}/Sqrt[2], 0, {0, 0, 1}, 
  1, {1, I, 0}/Sqrt[2]];

Clear[VectorSphericalHarmonicV];
VectorSphericalHarmonicV[ℓ_, J_, M_, θ_, ϕ_] /; 
  J >= 0 && ℓ >= 0 && Abs[J - ℓ] <= 1 &&  Abs[M] <= J := 
 Sum[If[Abs[M - λ] <= ℓ, 
    ClebschGordan[{ℓ, M - λ}, {1, λ}, {J, M}], 0]*
   SphericalHarmonicY[ℓ,   M - λ, θ, ϕ]*ϵ[λ], {λ, -1, 1}]

pp = Sum[(Random[NormalDistribution[]] + I Random[NormalDistribution[]]) 
Rest@ VectorSphericalHarmonicV[i, i - 1, i - 1, θ, ϕ], {i,2, 8}];
```

We can write

```
   gr2 = StreamPlot[pp//Re, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}, {θ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/2, Frame -> False, 
   StreamColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", StreamPoints -> 250];
   gr2 = gr2 /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[(cart /@ pts)] /. 
    Point[pts_] :> Point[cart[pts]] // 
   Show[#, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}] &;
```

and

```
Graphics[{Inset[mol, {-2, -1}, {0, 0}, {4, 2}], First[gr2]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I guess once we have a fast spherical harmonic code on the sphere it will be trivial to generalize it to vector fields.

### Update

This [`package`](https://github.com/User0815/cosmomathica) might be of relevance. I quote

> Wolfram Mathematica is a powerful and convenient software package used by many cosmologists everywhere. However, since it is not always the most efficient for low-level computing, most popular algorithms for numerical computations in cosmology have been written in C or Fortran, since these languages are typically much better suited for the task at hand. This package bundles the functionality of some of these algorithms in a Mathematica package, which makes them easier to use and avoids the need to learn C or Fortran.

Comment: @shrx thanks for the bounty!

Comment: are you sufficiently satisfied with either of the answers so I can award the bounty?

Comment: @shrx I guess I would rather leave it to you to decide?

Comment: To be honest neither answers your question sufficiently in my opinion, so I wouldn't award it.

Answer (score 6):

**GaussianRandomField** is a *special* case. More generally, what is required is *fast code* for the (inverse) Spherical Harmonic Transform (SHT), which will work for *any* coefficients $a_{l,m}$. [SHTns](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.6522.pdf) is a high performance library for Spherical Harmonic Transform written in C and so should be straightforward to link in using *MathLink*. It would be very nice if this code was built-in to a future version of *Mathematica*.

To see why fast code is required, for $l_{max} = 2^{12}$ direct computation requires evaluation of around $2^{24}$ spherical harmonics on your grid of $\theta$ and $\phi$ values (another factor of $2^{15}$). There are recursive tricks, of course, but fast methods rely on the FFT.

Regarding your example code, I do not see why you have (-1)^m in your definition for **alms[l, -m]**. To obtain an explicitly real function you should just have **alms[l, -m] = Conjugate@alms[l, m]**.

Further to your visualisation on the sphere, you can also select your view-centre, e.g. [Galactic Coordinates](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuyfonyllnilbt5/Galactic%20Coordinates.nb?dl=0).

Comment: Thanks for your indications. Regarding the code, if ` alms[l, -m] = Conjugate@alms[l, m].` then the map appears pi periodic horizontaly.

Comment: One could also use the library [libsharp](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2013/06/aa21494-13.pdf)

Comment: As stated above, a possible solution is to link Mathematica to a high performance external SHT library with MathLink. Among them there is the C GNU-GPL library libsharp (https://github.com/dagss/libsharp,
http://www.aanda.org/10.1051/0004-6361/201321494)
which has the advantage of supporting several different sphere
pixelisations (Gauss-Legendre, ECP, HEALPix, ...), and SHT of arbitrary spins.

Answer (score 5):

A part from efficiency, I noticed that with the definition below, lmax >= 64 works:

```
Clear[field];
field[θ_, ϕ_] :=
    Chop@
       Total[
          Table[
            alms[l, m] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ],
            {l, 0, lmax}, {m, -l, l}
          ]
      , 2
    ];


nn = 4.;
dat = ParallelTable[
    field[θ, ϕ],
         {θ, 0, Pi, Pi/nn},
         {ϕ, 0.,  2 Pi, 2 Pi/nn/2}
    ];

Round[Re[dat], 0.01]
```

> {
>    {0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51},
>
> {0.02, -1.54, -1.48, -0.47, -2.29, 0.61, 2.05, 1.82, 0.02},
>
> {0.24, -1.61, 0.44, 0.32, -0.55, 0.65, -1.12, -0.08, 0.24},
>
> {-0.34, 0.63, -0.54, 2.08, -0.72, 1.09, -2.09, -1.3, -0.34},
>
> {0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3} }

which looks better and produces a reasonable plot.

So, I tested also:

```
Clear[field];
field[θ_, ϕ_] :=
   Sum[
      alms[l, m] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θ, ϕ],
      {l, 0, lmax}, {m, -l, l}
   ];
```

and this too seems to me to work.

Consequently, it appears to me that Compile over Sum is doing some inappropriate manipulation.

**EDIT**

I could perhaps track down the problem a little better: it seems to be the SphericalHarmonicY at angles θ below Pi/4 and above Pi - Pi/4, which finally provide extremely high values in dat and hides the details of the other values (at least for lmax = 64).

For example the table:

```
dat = ParallelTable[
    fieldN[θ, ϕ],
        {θ, Pi/4., Pi - Pi/4., Pi/128.},
        {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/256.}
    ];
```

seems to me to produce a reasonable chart.