# How can I use Mathematica to convert a Mollweide projection map to Equirectangular?

Tags: plotting, graphics, projection

So, disclaimer, I have zero experience with Mathematica, and I apologize in advance.

I'd been looking for some software capable of converting between map projections for some time (in order to convert [this Mollweide map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea7Ge.png) to an equirectangular projection so that it may be more easily imported to other programs such as GPlates) when I stumbled across [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11834/how-do-i-map-a-mollweide-projection-onto-a-sphere) which, while a different goal, had a step which did exactly what I needed to do.

So, elated by this discovery, I downloaded the trial version of Mathematica, watched a couple videos to get a handle on the basics, and pasted the code from the thread into the program. However, when I hit "run code," It did...nothing. All I got was the following output:

```
ImageForwardTransformation[(original image of map), Null,
 DataRange -> {{-2 Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]}, {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

What am I doing wrong, and what can I do to make the code work?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: The code in the linked thread works fine for your image (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbATO.jpg). Are you sure `mollweidetoequirect` was defined correctly? The `Null` in your `ImageForwardTransformation` output makes me think it was incorrectly defined. Does running `ClearAll[mollweidetoequirect]` then redefining it fix things?